# Plist updates reading from bundle and writing to documents

Tags: ios

I asked this question earlier and I believe that I asked it incorrectly, so I am going to be more clear. The answer was very well thoughout and useful, for another time. I would like to know in my IOS Xcode ... I have a Master/Detail View template. I am loading the Master table view with Plist from the bundle, yet I am updating the Plist in the documents folder... how do I get those updates reflected in the bundle, and how do I refresh the screen. Please advise if you can. Thank you in advance.
Regards,

Here is my code to load the Master table ... does anything look incorrect: I am loading from Documents folder ... but I am not getting all of the records from documents:

```
NSLog(@"loading data");
    self.navigationItem.title=@"Accounts";
//    NSString *accountFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Accounts2" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *plistPath = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Accounts2.plist"];
    accounts = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
    account = [accounts objectForKey:@"Account"];
    number = [accounts objectForKey:@"Number"];
    dueDay = [accounts objectForKey:@"DayDue"];
    minAmount = [accounts objectForKey:@"MinAmount"];
    balance = [accounts objectForKey:@"Balance"];

    NSLog(@"data loaded");

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't update anything in the app bundle. It is read-only (at least on real iOS devices).

You must do all of your reading and writing of the plist file from a writable location such as the `Documents` folder. The first time you try to access the file, it won't exist. The solution is to copy the initial file from the app bundle. From then on you only read/write from/to the copy in `Documents`.

Comment: so, just for clarification... do I now load the Master table from the documents folder, which I tried and I am still getting the same number of records which were present in the bundle, sans the updates.  and thank you for your response, I do appreciate it.

Comment: Yes, all reading and updating of the plist file must be done with the copy in the Documents folder. The only use for the original in the resource bundle is to act as a starting copy the first time the app is run.

Comment: wow, that is helpful. thank you. BTW:                            here is my code to load my records: I am trying to load from the documents folder ... do you see anything wrong      NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *plistPath = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Accounts2.plist"];
    accounts = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

Comment: Update your question with the relevant code. Posting it in a comment makes it too hard to read and verify.